# How do I manipulate the columns in my financial data

Tags: python, finance

I've a dataframe in csv for different stock options and their close/high/low/open etc. But the format of the data is a bit difficult to work with. When calculating the returns using the adjusted close value, I've to create a new df each time to drop the null values.

[Original Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3iXC.png)

How do I convert it to the following format instead?

[Converted data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSzcp.png)

Answer (score 0):

The best way I could think of is to pivot the data:

```
# Drop date column (as it is already in the index), and pivot on Feature
df2 = df.drop(columns="Date").pivot(columns="Feature")
# Swap the column levels, so that Feature is first, then Ticker
df2 = df2.swaplevel(0, 1, 1)
# Stack the columns, so Ticker is one column, increasing the number of rows
df2 = df2.stack()
# Reset in the index, but keep it (the Date column)
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
# Sort the rows on the Ticker and Date
df2.sort_values(["level_1", "Date"], inplace=True)
# Rename the Ticker column
df2.rename(columns={"level_1": "Ticker"}, inplace=True)
# Reset the index
df2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

This could all be run once, rather than defining `df2` each time:

```
df2 = df.drop(columns="Date").pivot(columns="Feature") \
    .swaplevel(0, 1, 1).stack().reset_index() \
        .sort_values(["level_1", "Date"]) \
            .rename(columns={"level_1": "Ticker"}).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Hopefully this works for you!

Comment: Hi thanks so much,  I also realised I had to use the pivot function. My method was a little more troublesome than yours as I wasn't as familiar with python yet. But the steps are similar.